# How to send multiple asynchronous requests in parallel using Unirest

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, unirest

While using Unirest, the program doesn't exit until we manually shutdown every thread by invoking `Unirest.shutdown()`. If I had to make just one request, it's easy:

```
private static void asyncRequest (String link) {
    try {
        Future <HttpResponse <JsonNode>> request = Unirest.head(link).asJsonAsync(
                new Callback<JsonNode>() {
                    @Override
                    public void completed(HttpResponse<JsonNode> httpResponse) {
                        print(httpResponse.getHeaders());
                        try {
                            Unirest.shutdown();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failed(UnirestException e) {
                        print(e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void cancelled() {
                        print("Request cancelled");
                    }
                }
        );

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   asyncRequest("https://entrepreneur.com");
}
```

But I have to make multiple HTTP request in parallel (subsequent requests are meant not to wait for previous requests to complete). In the code above, I have to execute the code inside `asyncRequest` more than once with different `link`s. The problem is I can't decide when to invoke `Unirest.shutdown()` so that the program exits as soon as  the last request receives response. If I call `Unirest.shutdown()` after all the calls to `asyncRequest` in `main`, some or all the requests might get interrupted. If I call it inside `completed` (and other overridden methods), only the first request is made and others are interrupted. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you could make the current thread wait for the execution of the method and after they are all done you can call the shutdown. But this would make the whole process synchronous, which is not what we want. So what I would do is, run different thread (other than the main one) which will wait for the execution of all your http requests. To do so you can use the class `CountDownLatch`, initializing with the countdown before it releases the control to the parent thread. You pass the instance of the `CountDownLatch` to the `async` method and you decrease `by one` each time you complete an http request. When it reaches 0 it returns the control to the parent thread, where you know you can call `shutdown` method as all your requests are done.